Tissue rotation wrong
I'm new to blender, and I'm trying to use the Tissue add-on to create a pattern on a surface. The command Tessellate itself is pretty straightforward to use, but I get a strange rotation of the pattern in some points of my mesh, and I don't get why. Can you help? Here is a picture of the problem:

I just want the tiles to be all in the same direction, upwards.

Please share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

No need to share the blend file, of course there are ways to change the rotation of the tessellated tiles.

I guess you have extruded the object downwards or something like that? When you do that, it could be that the orientation of the new faces is different from the existing faces. And I do not mean backfaces pointing outwards, but the way the vertex indices are distributed (well but honestly I do not know which information is responsible for the rotation).
When you are adding tessellation, the new "Tessellation" object that is created has some more settings in the Object Data Properties tab. One of them is Rotation:

There are different options, the Default is naturally chosen. You could now for example choose Active UV and in case in the original object all faces had their UVs oriented in the same direction, so will the pattern be:

In my mesh this leads to all "arrows" pointing to the right though. To correct this, I can change the Shift value until all point upwards:

The important thing for this to work is: the UVs have to be correct on the original object before tessellation. Changes afterwards will not be incorporated. Also you cannot change the UV map on the tessellation object, this will have no effect either.
And here is an example how to use the Weight Gradient option:
When you paint a gradient on the original object like this, it automatically creates a vertex group called "Group" to store the weights.

Now you use the Tissue tool again, and in the Rotation settings of the "Tessellation" object you can now choose Weight Gradient and the Vertex Group called "Group" which was created in the original object. The arrows are pointing to the side but I can change this by Shift of course.

Or I could have painted the weight in a different direction right away:

But again, this has to be done on the original object before tessellation. Later changes will not be taken into account. Of course this can also vary from the orientation of the pattern which you are placing on the object.
That's just a "quick" overview, I'm not about to post a complete tutorial on the Tessellate tool. There are a lot more settings, but to get the pattern somehow aligned this should be helpful information.
//EDIT: Okay, one more short example how you can use weight painting for creating patterns. Here I selected every second horizontal edge loop, then added a vertex group and assigned those edges with a weight of 1. Then I used the weight paint group in the Tessellation with Weight Gradient and got this resulting pattern where the arrows are alternatingly changing directions:


Thank you, this seems to work!
